# scrollable fixed div

Tags: html, css

I have a menu in a div on the side of the browser and I would like to keep it in the fixed position. However, the menu may exceed height of some screens and that would result inaccessible links. So I would like to make the menu scrollable in such a case. Unfortunately the combination

```
position: fixed;
overflow: auto; (or scroll)
```

doesn't really work. I.e. the scrollbar is faded out (immovable). Is there a way? 
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The menu is similar to the one to the right up on [this page](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus). Only a bit larger. If you open that page and decrease the height of your browser window, part of the menu remains inaccessible. That's what I want to avoid. 
And no, my solution doesn't work in IE, Chrome, Opera or Firefox.

Comment: Please describe the problem more accurately or create a test page showing the difficulties you're having. "doesn't really work" isn't really descriptive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these to your declarations:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0; /* or height: 100%; */
```

You can replace the zeroes with larger values to add margins.