# How to create scrollable content in a fixed div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am in the process of creating a layout for a shopping cart I am designing for a restaurant food ordering website. I want to the shopping cart to be fixed, but as the user is adding items to the shopping cart I need to the cart to be scrollable there is an overflow.

This is just a quick and dirty example of the actual code I am trying to do this with.

I want to do is set a relative position inside the fixed position div, and make the cart id scrollable.

I have been trying to make this work for 5 hours, and I can't seem to find a solution.

```css
.wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%
}

.cart {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <div class='cart'>
      <div class='item'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam at leo in purus commodo tempor. Praesent ut euismod nunc, id vestibulum dolor. Morbi egestas vel tortor quis imperdiet. Mauris vitae dapibus leo. Pellentesque laoreet gravida dolor, sit
        amet suscipit erat consequat in. Curabitur interdum ut enim non consequat. Mauris eget nunc facilisis magna bibendum porttitor quis vitae nibh. Fusce accumsan justo ut vulputate luctus. Nam porta auctor dui eget facilisis. Fusce id tincidunt lectus.
        Praesent tristique semper lorem, non vulputate libero commodo ut. Maecenas efficitur imperdiet nisl posuere finibus. Phasellus dapibus sem lorem, vel lacinia ante suscipit eu. Morbi pulvinar ante viverra est laoreet, volutpat ullamcorper magna
        pellentesque. Suspendisse vitae augue eget massa mattis aliquam. Donec ac mi in felis finibus cursus. Mauris a molestie lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam vehicula enim non elit
        elementum hendrerit. Suspendisse vel fermentum ligula, ut vulputate est. Quisque sagittis, velit in rhoncus interdum, justo dui elementum leo, viverra placerat ligula tortor vel justo. Curabitur interdum egestas leo in elementum. Etiam molestie
        sit amet tortor et rhoncus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum iaculis massa bibendum arcu volutpat egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam convallis libero nec dapibus dictum.
        Suspendisse venenatis velit tellus, sit amet volutpat leo lacinia et. Nulla a ligula blandit, sollicitudin justo a, ornare velit. In pellentesque sem nisl, vitae pulvinar orci euismod a. Aenean egestas, ipsum vitae lacinia volutpat, orci ante
        dapibus diam, vitae varius leo nisl ut nibh. Mauris vulputate ac lacus in auctor. Cras facilisis mattis elementum. Pellentesque egestas quam eget massa fringilla, at tincidunt augue pulvinar. Phasellus aliquet a metus et dignissim. Suspendisse
        vitae porttitor felis, eu lacinia libero. Donec non enim a dui scelerisque interdum ac vitae nisi. Fusce molestie quam metus, at molestie diam finibus sed. Proin quis diam felis. Integer viverra cursus pretium. Maecenas varius augue sed lacus
        porttitor feugiat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin tincidunt urna vitae lacus placerat, ac rutrum ligula tristique. Sed vitae neque mollis, faucibus orci et, scelerisque nisi. Cum sociis
        natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec commodo lorem felis. Proin et convallis nulla, rutrum congue ante. Donec nunc lacus, rutrum et blandit eget, accumsan vel ipsum. Sed id justo urna. Donec ullamcorper,
        justo id fermentum tincidunt, justo arcu eleifend augue, quis consectetur ex est in erat. Pellentesque eleifend a nisl ut scelerisque. Pellentesque ut lectus orci. Donec at lobortis nisl, quis scelerisque velit. Nam arcu sapien, ultricies sit
        amet tellus at, blandit ornare neque. Duis congue malesuada erat sit amet placerat. Curabitur viverra ex nec rutrum vulputate. Integer ullamcorper nisi nec euismod efficitur. Duis scelerisque vehicula elit, vitae ultricies nulla sagittis sit amet.
        Duis venenatis nulla non sem scelerisque eleifend. Vestibulum ultrices lorem lorem, id molestie mi ultrices sed. Ut hendrerit felis ligula, eu bibendum ante efficitur eget. Duis dui neque, aliquet semper sagittis vel, posuere vitae lorem. Vestibulum
        nec ligula at ex luctus molestie et vitae leo. Nullam quis mi volutpat, aliquet erat at, luctus massa.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrollable fixed div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150177/scrollable-fixed-div)

Answer (score 0):

Add this .item to your style and set height, it should work.

```
  .wrapper {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      position: fixed;
      width: 200px;
    }

    .sidebar {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%
    }

    .cart {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .item{
     overflow-y: auto;
     height:200px;
    }
```